# Pasar los datos a un modal

Tags: php, html, modal, tailwind

Tengo una lista de archivos con un boton de "eliminar archivo", el botón funciona pero para evitar errores y eliminar sin querer, decidí añadir un modal que sirva de alerta antes de eliminar el archivo.

Estoy utilizando PHP para recuperar los datos y tailwind con flowbite para los estilos.

El botón que tenía para eliminar (y que funciona) es el siguiente:

```
<a href="../../controller/files/delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['idArchivo'] ?>" class="text-red-500" data-modal-toggle="deleteModal">
  <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"></path>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Y lo cambié por el siguiente código:

```
<button class="block text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center  bg-blue-600  hover:bg-blue-700  focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="deleteModal" targetEl="">Eliminar</button>
```

modal:

```
<div id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" class="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full">
  <div class="relative w-full h-full max-w-md md:h-auto">
    <div class="relative rounded-lg shadow bg-gray-700">
      <button type="button" class="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center hover:bg-gray-800 hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="deleteModal">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
      </button>
      <div class="p-6 text-center">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="mx-auto mb-4 w-14 h-14  text-gray-200" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 8v4m0 4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path>
        </svg>
        <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-400">Are you sure you want to delete this product?</h3>


        <!-- Botón que me interesa -->
        <a href="../../controller/files/delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['idArchivo'] ?>" data-modal-toggle="deleteModal" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2">Eliminar
        </a>

        
        <button data-modal-toggle="deleteModal" type="button" class="focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none rounded-lg bordertext-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 focus:z-10  bg-gray-700  text-gray-300  border-gray-500  hover:text-white  hover:bg-gray-600  focus:ring-gray-600">No, cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede ver, funciona pasando el id del archivo a través de la url y con una petición SQL se elimina de la base de datos, sin embargo, intenté hacer eso mismo con el modal pero no funciona.

Es primera vez que trabajo con modales y por lo que entiendo funcionan como otro archivo el cuál no tiene relación con el anterior, por lo que pasar el id con `$row['idArchivo']` entiendo que no funciona.

EL modal lo saqué de aquí: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/#pop-up-modal y creo que quizás tengo que utilizar el parametro de objeto `targetEl` pero no sé exactamente lo que es ni cómo podría utilizarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer que tu botón tenga un evento `onclick` para que al presionarlo se dispare el evento, dentro puedes agregarle una función a la que le pasaras un parámetro, en este caso el id del archivo, seria algo así:

```
<button class="block text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center  bg-blue-600  hover:bg-blue-700  focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="deleteModal" targetEl="" onclick="deleteArchive('<?php echo($row['idArchivo']); ?>')">Eliminar</button>
```

Agrega un `id` al botón de Eliminar dentro del modal, y deja el `href` con el valor  `javascript::void(0);`

```
<a href="javascript::void(0);" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2" id="btnArchiveDelete">Eliminar
    </a>
```

Luego crea la función en JavaScript que declaraste en el evento `onclick`, seria asi:

```js
function deleteArchive(id) {
  var element=document.querySelector('#btnArchiveDelete');
  element.setAttribute('href', '../../controller/files/delete.php?id='+id);
}
```

Lo que hace es tomar el id que pasaste como parámetro en la función y editar el valor del `href` dentro del botón de tu modal, para que al hacer click en el botón te redireccione a donde quieres

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias de verdad. Ahora, esto funciona, pero ¿hacerlo de esta manera es una practica recomendada? ¿Hay otras opciones?

Comment: Hacerlo con la función js y utilizando un evento click si seria recomendado porque es algo recursivo que puedes utilizar bien, te daría una recomendación sobre esto, y es que uses un método POST para cuando quieras eliminar, ya que de esta manera no se podrá acceder a la url de eliminar por medio de GET, para hacerlo solo agrega una etiqueta form en el modal y en vez de cambiar el href del botón, cambia el atributo action para que vaya a la url que quieres, esa seria una forma un tanto mejor

Comment: Muchas gracias!